# HTML Drag and Drop API IE11 issue

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-11

In the MDN web docs for HTML Drag and drop API their first example has some issues in IE11, that I am also experiencing in my code. When the user drags over a drop the icon under the cursor flickers rapidly. Here is the example

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Any ideas as to why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: My apologies, the link is to the api documentation. here is the link to the actual example they have that i'm referencing https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/drag-and-drop/copy-move-DataTransfer.html

Comment: After testing and searching, I think that this is a browser behavior of IE. Since IE is an old version browser, there is no helpful solution and any updated fix for this. The only suggestion is that you could move to the latest browser Microsoft Edge. I've tested that there will be no such behavior appear.